# Show that for each $p \in P(n)$, the set $A(p) = \{x \mid p(x) = 0\}$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis

Show that for each $p \in P_n\;$, the set $\;A(p) = \{x \mid p(x) = 0\}\;$ is countable.
  Where $P_n$ is the set of all polynomials of degree $n$ with integer coefficients.

I just proved that $P_n$ is countable.   My issue here is I just do not understand fully what the question is trying to ask me to prove is countable.   It almost seems like it's asking me to prove that all algebraic numbers are countable but that's the next question...

Some clarification would be helpful. I am simply rewriting what my professor has assigned.

This is what I've come up with so far (not very good)

Using the fact that any polynomial with integer coefficients and degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots, we can directly conclude that the set of all roots is finite, and thus countable. Now, If we consider all the roots of every polynomial, we have infinite union of countable sets, and thus the set of all roots to all polynomials with integer coefficients and degree $n$ are countable by the fact that the infinite union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: You said “$P(n)$” in two places and “$P_n$” in two places.  Did you mean those to be all the same?

Comment: Isn't there a theorem of algebra that if $p\in P_n$ then $\{x \mid p(x) = 0\}$ has at most $n$ elements?

Comment: Hint:  Think about the relation between the roots of a polynomial and its factors.

Comment: @mjd I don't see the issue.

Comment: @WillO I just don't particularly understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea you can use to prove this is that a polynomial $P$ of degree $n$ cannot have *more* than $n$ roots (in the complex numbers). This is a simpler statement to prove than the fundamental theorem of algebra, which says that such a polynomial has *exactly* $n$ roots, counting multiplicity. In particular, you can prove this statement inductively; clearly, a polynomial of degree $0$ (i.e. a non-zero constant polynomial) cannot have more than $0$ roots. For the inductive step, notice that if $k$ is a root of $P$, then $Q(x)=\frac{P(x)}{x-k}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. So if $Q(x)$ has no more than $n-1$ roots, $P(x)=Q(x)\cdot (x-k)$ must have no more than $n$. This implies that each set $A(P)$ has *finitely* many elements, bounded by the degree of the polynomial.

This looks to be essentially the idea that you already have - and I think it's a complete answer to the question as it is. For any $P$, it holds that $A(P)$ is finite, hence countable. This is what you're being asked to prove. I assume the next step you're meant to take is "Well, the union of all $A(P)$, which is the algebraic numbers, is a countable union of countable sets, and is therefore countable" - which is essentially what you've already written (which is getting a little ahead of the current problem). It is worthy of note that you have "an *infinite* union of countable sets", where we actually need the stronger hypothesis that it is a *countable* union of countable sets. Other than that, you clearly have the right idea.

(It is not immediately obvious that $\frac{P(x)}{x-k}$ is actually a polynomial if $k$ is a root, but you can easily prove that by using polynomial long division to see that there is no remainder when dividing $x-k$ if and only if $k$ is a root - and when there is no remainder, the quotient is clearly a polynomial)

Comment: Could you take a look at my attempt and tell me how that seems?

Comment: @Frumpy I edited that into my answer; in short: your attempt looks fine. I think the question your professor gave is awfully unclear as it is - and I doubt anyone would begrudge you if you, as you did, just jumped to proving that the algebraic numbers are countable (which certainly implies any subset thereof, like $A(P)$ is countable too)

Comment: Yes the next question is to prove that the set of all algebraic numbers is countable and that's basically using the fact the infinite union of countable sets is countable. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $P_n$ is the set of polynomials with $n$ integer coefficients and $\;p\in P_n\;$ then $\;A(p) = \{x \mid p(x) = 0\}\;$ is the set of roots to a *specified* polynomial with $n$ integer coefficients.

Hence it appears that you are required to prove: That a polynomial with $n$ integer coefficients has a countable number of roots (that is, solutions for $x$ to the equation $p(x)=0$).

Comment: Is there any hint you can give me to guide me in the right direction? I don't particularly know where to start other than the fact that we know that the polynomial has $n$ number of coefficients where if we add each integer coefficient we get $M$.